# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "codigo"

Tags: java, jsf-2.2

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto com JSF, primefaces, maven e JPA com a especificação do hibernate e SGBD PostgreeSQL (criei o script do banco de dados separado, depois conectei com hibernate) e ao tentar executar a página de listar todos os clientes, estou obtendo a seguinte exceção:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "codigo"

eu não entendo o por quê ocorre este erro já que o "código" (id do cliente) é do tipo Integer e no banco de dados também é INTEGER. No teste no método main funciona sem problema.

minha página JSF:

```
<ui:composition template="./../template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="SYS_MARKET CONNECT">
                SYS_MARKET CONNECT
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="left">
                left
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="right">
                right
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form>

                    <p:dataTable var="cliente" value="#{controlerCliente.obterClientes()}" rows="3" rowKey="#{cliente.codigo}"
                                 selection="#{controlerCliente.selectClientes}" selectionMode="single" paginator="true">

                        <p:column headerText="CODIGO: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.codigo}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="NOME: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.nome}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="CPF: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.cpf}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="DATA CADASTRO">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.dataAbertura}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="E-MAIL: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.email}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="TELEFONE: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.telefone}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="RUA: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.endereco.bairro}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="NÚMERO: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.endereco.numero}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="CEP: ">
                            <h:outputText value="#{cliente.endereco.cep}"/>
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>
```

segue minha classe cliente:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package model.entidade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 *
 * @author Daniel
 */
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer codigo;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataAbertura;

    @Column()
    private String cpf;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String telefone;

    @Embedded
    private Endereco endereco;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente_id", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Venda> venda;

    public Cliente(Integer codigo, String nome, Date dataAbertura, String cpf, String email, String telefone, Endereco endereco) {

        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Cliente() {

    }

    public Integer getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nome
     */
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    /**
     * @param nome the nome to set
     */
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dataAbertura
     */
    public Date getDataAbertura() {
        return dataAbertura;
    }

    /**
     * @param dataAbertura the dataAbertura to set
     */
    public void setDataAbertura(Date dataAbertura) {
        this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telefone
     */
    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    /**
     * @param telefone the telefone to set
     */
    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    /**
     * @return the cpf
     */
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    /**
     * @param cpf the cpf to set
     */
    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public Endereco getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.codigo);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.nome);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.dataAbertura);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.cpf);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.email);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.telefone);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.endereco);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.venda);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.nome, other.nome)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.cpf, other.cpf)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.email, other.email)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.telefone, other.telefone)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.codigo, other.codigo)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.dataAbertura, other.dataAbertura)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.endereco, other.endereco)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.venda, other.venda)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cliente{" + "codigo=" + codigo + ", nome=" + nome + ", dataAbertura=" + dataAbertura + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", email=" + email + ", telefone=" + telefone + ", endereco=" + endereco + ", venda=" + venda + '}';
    }

}
```

controler (clienteBean):

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ControlerCliente implements Serializable{

    private Cliente cliente;
    private transient ClienteModel clienteModel;
    private Endereco endereco;
    private List<Cliente> selectClientes = null;

        public ControlerCliente() {

        this.endereco = new Endereco();
        this.clienteModel = new ClienteModel();
        this.cliente=new Cliente();
        this.selectClientes = new ArrayList<>();

    }





listar todos da implementação do DAO:





@Override
    public List<Cliente> recuperarTodos() {
         entityManager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            Query consult = entityManager.createQuery("select c from Cliente c");
            clientes = consult.getResultList();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("erro ao listar os clientes");
            e.printStackTrace();
            entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally{
            entityManager.close();
        }
        return clientes;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece pelo fato do atributo `rowKey` do componente `p:dataTable` for do tipo String e você estar passando um `Integer(id)`.

O que você pode fazer é criar um método que devolve esse atributo como String, por exemplo:

```
public String getCodigoString(){
    String.valueOf(this.codigo);
}
```

e utilizar como `rowKey`esse método:

```
<p:dataTable var="cliente" value="#{controlerCliente.obterClientes()}" rows="3" 
    rowKey="#{cliente.codigoString}" 
    selection="#{controlerCliente.selectClientes}" selectionMode="single" paginator="true">
```

Comment: fiz as alterações, porém não funcionou continua dando o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema parecido porem o meu era com conversão de valores, onde meu erro ocorria porque estava digitando o atributo diretamente apenas com this.
EXEMPLO:

```
 int hash = 3;
 hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.codigo);

 //EM VEZ DISSO USE:

hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.getCodigo());     //use os getters e os setters
```

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema e a solução foi a seguinte:

Meu dataTable era para single select mas apontava pra uma lista
<p:dataTable selection="#{controller.listaSelecionada}" rowKey="#{obj.id}"

Alterei para:
<p:dataTable selection="#{controller.objSelecionado}" rowKey="#{obj.id}"

E funcionou!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Olha, o comentário é pertinente porque esse erro pode estar relacionado com o uso errado do atributo selection, ou até o uso desnessário do mesmo. Tirá-lo pode ser um bom começo para pelo menos eliminar essa possibilidade.